# Why does my Location not display within my Emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-location, android-gps

I followed the steps on how to setup my Location within an Emulator to display the GPS location of anywhere on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start

When I go to add a location within my Emulator and when Google Maps opens it shows the Google logo bottom left and is just a empty Maps screen with no location, I get this error in my Logcat when I click 'Add Location'

```
2021-04-25 22:01:33.260 9379-9456/org.wit.letter E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
2021-04-25 22:01:33.261 9379-9456/org.wit.letter E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
    Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
    Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
```

I made sure to check I was using the right keys and I was with the correct fingerprint and I also made sure within the Cloud Console that the Maps SDK for Android was enabled but it still doesn't display Google Maps with GPS tracking.

Comment: you test on a real device and it worked ?

Comment: If you used a maps activity template, it should have created a xml where you put the key, if that's not your case you need to store it and declared it on your mafiest as a meta data

Comment: I placed the key ID within the google_maps_api.xml which is where I was told to place my Android Key, it knows as it shows my correct fingerprint ID that I didn't input after placing the Key ID

Comment: I tested it on Android Emulator which should work just as well.